# Quero mudar a cor do button de acordo com o valor da variavel

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, button

Criei uma condição de if/elseif dentro do foreache, para mudar a cor do button do status do pagamento. Tenho tres status e são tres cores para casa status. Só que ele não ta pegando as cores. Acho que o problema esta na hora de dclarar os valores para a variavel. vou mandar um print da minha tela.

[image: Minha tela]

```
 <?php
                    $query = $this->sindico->get_listfinanceiro()->result();
                    foreach ($query as $linha):
                        echo '<tr>';
                        printf('<td>%s / %s</td>', ($linha->numero_apart) ? :'/', ($linha->nome_usu));
                        printf('<td>%s</td>', $linha->data_pagamento);
                        printf('<td>%s</td>', "Bs:".$linha->valor_pagamento);
                        $class = "" ;
                        if (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento["PAGO"])){
                            $class =  'btn-sucesso' ;}

                        elseif (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento["PENDENTE"])){
                            $class =  'btn-warning' ;}

                        elseif (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento['NO PAGO'])){
                            $class =  'btn-danger' ;}
                        printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn '.$class.' btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);
                        printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', '<div class="btn-group btn-xs"><button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle"  data-original-title="" title="">Action<span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right"><li><a href="editar/'.$linha->id_finan.'">Edit</a></li><li><a href="excluir/'.$linha->id_finan.'">Delete</a></li>' );

                        echo '</tr>';
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
```

Comment: Se você estiver usando o bootstrap então a classe correta é **btn-success**. Verificou se realmente está entrando no _if_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque `!isset` por `isset`. Se `$linha` foi inicializada `echo "sucess"`!

Answer (score 0):

De forma geral se você trocar `!isset` por `isset` vai funcionar...

Mas, só por desencargo, faça um debug vendo se está entrando no `if`, bote um `exit('Aqui')` dentro do `if`pra ter certeza que está entrando...

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou trocar:

- btn-sucesso por btn-success
- !isset por isset
- e para danger poderia ser só um else

  ```
  <?php
     $query = $this->sindico->get_listfinanceiro()->result();
     foreach ($query as $linha):
       echo '<tr>';
         printf('<td>%s / %s</td>', ($linha->numero_apart) ? :'/', ($linha->nome_usu));
         printf('<td>%s</td>', $linha->data_pagamento);
         printf('<td>%s</td>', "Bs:".$linha->valor_pagamento);
         $class = "" ;
         if (isset($linha->valor_pagamento['PAGO'])){
            $class =  'btn-success' ;
         }

         elseif (isset($linha->valor_pagamento['PENDENTE'])){
            $class =  'btn-warning' ;
         } else {
            $class =  'btn-danger' ;
         }

         printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn '.$class.' btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);
         printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', '<div class="btn-group btn-xs"><button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle"  data-original-title="" title="">Action<span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right"><li><a href="editar/'.$linha->id_finan.'">Edit</a></li><li><a href="excluir/'.$linha->id_finan.'">Delete</a></li>' );

       echo '</tr>';
     endforeach;
  ?>
  ```